# Saving decrypted binary file in Vim results in "Conversion Error"

Tags: vim

If I open a .RAR file in Vim, encrypt it (using :X and blowfish) and save, then reopen it and decrypt it, I get a "Conversion Error" when I try to save it.

I have since tried setting the :binary setting prior to opening both the original and the encrypted files, but I get the same error. I've tried changing the encoding to utf-8, but then WinRar/7zip can't open the resulting file.

Even if I can't recover the original file I've encrypted, I'd like to know how to avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: What Vim version is this?

Comment: Please, show the exact version output

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2014 Aug 10, compiled Aug 10 2013 14:38:33)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support

Comment: Get a newer version. I believe this is a bug, that has been fixed with 7.4.730

Comment: New version seems to be working better. Thanks!